Type describing an object property path as string array
Let's say I have an arbitrarily deep TypeScript interface that describes an app's state like:
interface MyState {
    foo: boolean;
    bar: {
        baz: string;
        bur: {
            pir: string;
            par: { pew: boolean }[]
        }
    }
}

I now want to write a type that allows me to constrain an array of strings to describes a valid path to an arbitrary point in an object adhering to that interface. E.g. all of those should be correct:
myPath: PathType<MyState> = ["foo"];
myPath = ["bar", "baz"];
myPath = ["bar", "bur"];
myPath = ["bar", "bur", "par"];
Array handling would be cool like:
myPath = ["bar", "bur", "par", 1, "pew"];

Invalid:
myPath = ["baz"];
myPath = ["bar", "pir"];
myPath = ["any", "random", "crap"];

I have tried approaches like this:
type PathType<State, Key extends keyof State = keyof State> =
    State extends object ?
        [Key, ...PathType<State[Key], keyof State[Key]>] : never;

But they all seem to fail with the recursion, only the first entry of the array is typed correctly, then it accepts everything.

Does this approach meet your needs? (Before you respond, please test thoroughly against your use cases; these sorts of deep recursive types tend to have bizarre edge cases that require significant refactoring to handle.) If so, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Please note that such deeply recursive types tend to have bizarre edge cases that need significant refactoring to handle. The code as shown here works for the examples in the question, but future readers with ostensibly similar requirements might not  be able to use it directly. So beware.

Given the example, I'd be inclined to make PathTuple<T> a recursive conditional type where the second generic type parameter A acts is the path to the current object.
type PathTuple<T, A extends PropertyKey[] = []> = T extends object ? (
    A | { [I in keyof T]: PathTuple<T[I], [...A, I]>
    }[keyof T & (T extends readonly any[] ? number : unknown)]
) : A;

The base case is that T is not an object, and in this case we just return the accumulated paths. Otherwise we return the union of A and a distributive object type (as coined in ms/TS#47109) mostly of the form {[I in keyof T]: PathTuple<T[I], [...A, I]>}[keyof T].  That recurses into the properties of T and for each property with key I, appends I to the result of PathTuple for that property.  Note that when you write {[I in K]: F<I>}[K] you end up with the union of F<I> for every I in K.  The only wrinkle is if T is an array type, then the mapped type will be an array, but keyof T will include all the keys we don't want to include like length and push; we only want the numeric keys of T for arrays.  So the type keyof T & (T extends readonly any[] ? number : unknown) will be keyof T if T isn't arraylike, but will be number if it is.

Let's test it out:
let myPath: PathTuple<MyState>;
/* let myPath: [] | ["foo"] | ["bar"] | ["bar", "baz"] | ["bar", "bur"] | 
   ["bar", "bur", "pir"] | ["bar", "bur", "par"] | ["bar", "bur", "par", number] | 
   ["bar", "bur", "par", number, "pew"] 
*/
myPath = ["foo"];
myPath = ["bar", "baz"];
myPath = ["bar", "bur"];
myPath = ["bar", "bur", "par"];
myPath = ["bar", "bur", "par", 1, "pew"];
myPath = ["baz"]; // error
myPath = ["bar", "pir"]; // error
myPath = ["any", "random", "crap"]; // error

Looks good.
Playground link to code

Thanks @jcalz, your comment was the correct answer.
I added a predicate function for the array and slightly modified it, this works for me now:
type PredicateFunction<ArrayType> = (array: ArrayType, index?: number) => boolean;
        
type PathTuple<T, A extends (PropertyKey | PredicateFunction<any>)[] = []> = 
  T extends readonly any[] ? 
    A | PathTuple<T[number], [...A, number | PredicateFunction<T[number]>]> : 
    T extends object ?
       A | PathTuple<T[keyof T], [...A, keyof T]> : 
       A;


? I don’t understand. If you read my comment then you know I offered to write an answer with an explanation for how it works, or to address any unmet use cases. Instead you wrote your own answer and accepted it, with no explanation except for how it differs from my suggestion.  Is there a reason for this? Is it just a communication lapse? Would it still be worthwhile for me to write an answer post with an actual explanation in it?

Sorry @jcalz I thought the source is self explaining and sufficient. If you want to write an explanation for others, that would be great and I would ofc mark it as the right answer - just didn't want to steal your time (maybe I just don't know good enough how the bounty system here works).

Btw., the solution has the flaw that the Typescript compiler (v5.4.5) complains about the recursion: "TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite." Maybe you know a solution for that?

Where is that happening? I didn’t see that problem. Are you talking about your added bit with predicate functions?

@jcalz yes in my version. when i use the interface and I try to iterate over an array with that typing, the compiler (tsc) throws that error at compile time. the language service of the ide is not complaining.

I... I'm not prepared to answer a question about your version; I haven't even looked at it, nor does it quite seem to be on-topic for the question as asked (surely nothing about "predicate functions" was part of your original question). This answer and your comment feel like you're trying to move past the original question and ask a new question. That would be better done in a separate post, and not a comment section.

@jcalz you are right the compiler error is out of scope. I will try to solve it on my own and create a new question in case I fail. Thanks for your solution.
